# Create nested lists from a dynamically created single list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of LI elements with class of .l1 .l2 .l3 etc for how many levels deep it should be.

What I need to do is if a li.l1 next element is an li.l2 wrap all of them in a ul and move them within the li.l1, but it needs to stop when it hits the next li.l1

Basically Im trying to format this single list into a series of nested lists based on their class names. Plus it needs to work for each of the sub lists that are created.

So simply put, I need to turn this...

```
<ul>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l3">Text</li>
<li class="l4">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l2">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
<li class="l1">Text</li>
```

Into this...

```
<ul>
    <li class="l1">Text1</li>
    <li class="l1">Text1
    <ul>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2
        <ul>
            <li class="l3">Text3
            <ul>
                <li class="l4">Text4</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="l1">Text1</li>
    <li class="l1">Text1</li>
    <li class="l1">Text1
    <ul>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="l1">Text1
    <ul>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
        <li class="l2">Text2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="l1">Text1</li>
    <li class="l1">Text1</li>
    <li class="l1">Text1</li>
</ul>
```

I know i can wrap elements of a certain class using jQuery wrapAll() but not sure how to make it stop when it hits an item with a different class, then skip over these and start a new wrap for the next set.

I was thinking something along the lines of li.l1.next().siblings('li.l2') but just dont know jQuery enough to flesh it out properly!

The best I've een able to come up with so far is this...

```
$('.sitemap li.l1').each(function(){ 
    $(this).nextUntil('.l1').wrapAll('<ul></ul>'); 
})
$('.sitemap li.l2').each(function(){ 
    $(this).nextUntil('.l2').wrapAll('<ul></ul>'); 
})         
$('.sitemap li.l3').each(function(){ 
    $(this).nextUntil('.l3').wrapAll('<ul></ul>'); 
})                 
$('.sitemap li.l4').each(function(){ 
    $(this).nextUntil('.l4').wrapAll('<ul></ul>'); 
})
```

But this doesnt nest the lists, just wraps elements

Cheers, R.

Comment: As this is not a trivial question, please post some code to prove you have at least attempted this yourself.

Comment: The best I've een able to come up with so far is this...

$('.sitemap li.l1').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.l1').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
 })


$('.sitemap li.l2').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.l2').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
 })

$('.sitemap li.l3').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.l3').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
 })

$('.sitemap li.l4').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('.l4').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
 })

But this doesnt nest the lists, just wraps elements.

Comment: It seems like you need to do this recursively until each `ul` contains only `li` elements with the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? I went into a slightly different way, not using `.wrapAll()`. Maybe you can tweak it and get back to your original idea. It works this way though.

```
$("li", "ul.sitemap").each(function () {
    var subElements = $(this).nextUntil("li[class=" + $(this).attr("class") + "]");
    if (subElements.length > 0) {
        var wrapped = $("<ul class='sitemap' />").append(subElements);
        $(this).append($(wrapped));
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sW58K/1/

Comment: Excellent mate, thats perfect. Appreciate you taking time to help out on that.